# finding the inverse of the exponential CDF

Tags: self-learning, sampling

I'm trying to find the inverse transform of the exponential CDF to sample from it (make x the subject of the equation)

see the examples section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling

Attempt 1:

$$ y=1-e^{-\lambda x} $$

$$ 1-y = e^{-\lambda x} $$

$$ log(1-y) = -\lambda x $$

$$ x = -log(1-y)/\lambda $$

Attempt 2:

$$ y=1-e^{-\lambda x} $$

$$ y-1 = -e^{-\lambda x} $$

$$ log(y-1) = \lambda x $$

$$ x = log(y-1)/\lambda $$

question: Is $ -log(1-y)/\lambda \equiv log(y-1)/\lambda $

If not, what have I done wrong?

Comment: You can't take log(-e) =/=log(e) since the lhs is undefined

Comment: why can't you do -1*log(e)?

Comment: Log is not defined for negative values, look at the plot of log(x) .- 1log(e) =log( e^(-1))=log (1/e) by properties of log and exponentials.

Comment: Could the person that down voted this question please explain why?

Comment: Wasn't me but it's not really a stats question, more an algebraic /maths one.